# Getting PHP regular expression limit error

Tags: php, joomla

I am using Joomla and getting [this error](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/650961/cac444ec3e4fe4ebedc04475ab0f4dbb)
on a [page](http://charteryacht.eu/index.php/blog) of my site

Error Message :

> 0 - PHP regular expression limit reached (pcre.backtrack_limit)

I have searched on google and found few solutions like 
add these two lines on joomla's root index.php file or on configuration.php file

```
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit',1000000);
ini_set('pcre.recursion_limit',1000000);
```

but didn't work for me.
So can you please help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello Pedro,
Sorry but i am getting second time this thing "How to Ask".
Sorry for that.
But can you please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I think question's format is OK :)

Comment: Question doesn't have the error or any code.

Comment: I have no knowledge about Joomla so I need to ask. You are adding thene ini_set() lines to top of your bootstrap file (it's probably configuration.php file) right? Also if you have any caching plugin, disable it or flush cache

Comment: i have added a screenshot as well as url of site where i am getting the error

Comment: You realize that we can't access that page right? Most likely it's because we're not members of that site.

Comment: @AtulSoni, please copy that error message and add to you question. chris85 is right about that. Everyone should see the error message without clicking anything.

Comment: Yes Eray i have added these lines in configuration.php file as well as joomla's root folder index.php file and i am not using any cache plugin and default cache plugin is disabled.

Comment: Try modifying your php.ini file instead of using ini_set()

Comment: @AtulSoni http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520019/php-regular-expression-limit-reached-pcre-backtrack-limit

Comment: You may want to take into consideration that it's an extension you possibly have installed on your Joomla site. Try disabling any recently installed extensions one by one to try and find the culprit.
@frosty - As per your first comment, it's not Joomla that's the issue

Comment: @Lodder i have checked the extensions and found no extension is causing this issue

Comment: Maybe you should modify your regex pattern this is what they are suggesting in same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520019/php-regular-expression-limit-reached-pcre-backtrack-limit

Comment: Please turn error reporting to "development" and turn on debugging, both done in global configuration.  Is this happening on every page or only some pages? Also check your apache error log and copy and paste any message there into your question.

Comment: Can you turn on error reporting and debugging? It's definitely not Joomla, it's a regex function on that specific page.

Comment: Yes you are right i am getting this only on a single page not on all pages

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your version of PHP?

Talk to your ISP

Read:
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=622839

Answer (score -1):

The most important question is, are you getting the error requesting a page that's larger than average?? If so, this most likely is a SEF error. Then switch off SEF in the Joomla Configuration and try again; if things work, then you are the next victim of the problem described in this Joomla page:  :http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=24865
In other words, it's a known Joomla problem, but apparently the Joomla people think it's not important, and in any case have closed the issue. My guess is the SEF plugin should be re-written not to use PCRE in scanning the content page the way it does. This is a frustrating issue that has existed for years !!

There's one other tip: when you want to keep SEF switched on: try disabling the SEF system plugin this is reported to solve the issue with no or very limited side effects (e.g. SEF will still work as the plugin only provides a few extras for SEF).