# After adding .* before my pattern, preg_match can not match. Is this a preg_match bug?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My code snip is like this:

```
$blockname='EDUCATION';

preg_match(
    '/(<w:p\s.*>\${' . $blockname . '}<\/w:.*?p>)(.*)(<w:p\s.*>\${\/' . $blockname . '}<\/w:.*?p>)/s',
    $string,
    $matches
);

print_r($matches);

preg_match(
    '/(.*)(<w:p\s.*>\${' . $blockname . '}<\/w:.*?p>)(.*)(<w:p\s.*>\${\/' . $blockname . '}<\/w:.*?p>)/s',
    $string,
    $matches
);

print_r($matches);
```

The first preg_match can match, but the second can't.
Is this a preg_match bug? How do you think?

You can download testing file here [preg_match_bug.php](http://www.filedropper.com/pregmatchbug)

OK, full code here
tl;dr

```
<?php

$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se wp14"><w:background w:color="FFFFFF"/><w:body><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"/><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>个</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>人</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>资</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>料</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>姓名：</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="006A378C"><w:tab/></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="006A378C"><w:tab/></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00CA06C6"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a7"/><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>${Name}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>gender：</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:tab/></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="006A378C"><w:tab/></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00CA06C6"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a7"/><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>${Sex}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>year：</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:tab/></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00CA06C6"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a7"/><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>${Birth}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>M：</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:tab/></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="00CA06C6"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a7"/><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>${Married}</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="006A378C" w:rsidRDefault="006A378C" w:rsidP="0002737E"/><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>教</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>育</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>经</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>历</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="00FF77A7" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${EDUCATION}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:t>${EDU_StartDate}-${EDU_EndDate}</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:tab/><w:t>${EDU_School}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:t>${EDU_Specialit}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:t>${EDU_Education}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="00FF77A7" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/EDUCATION}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="006A378C" w:rsidRDefault="006A378C" w:rsidP="0002737E"/><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>培</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>训</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>经</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>历</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="006166EE" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="006166EE"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${TRAINING}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="a5"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr><w:ind w:firstLineChars="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${TRN_StartDate}-${TRN_EndDate}</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:tab/><w:t>${TRN_School}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:t>${TRN_Education}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="006166EE" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="006166EE"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/TRAINING}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="006A378C" w:rsidRDefault="006A378C" w:rsidP="0002737E"/><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>语</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>言</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>能</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>力</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>英</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">    </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>语：</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:tab/><w:t>${English}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>普</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>通</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>话：</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:tab/><w:t>${Mandarin}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>粤</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">    </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>语：</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:tab/><w:t>${Cantonese}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>其</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">    </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>他：</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:tab/><w:t>${Others}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>电</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>脑</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>技</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>能</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="006A378C"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="a5"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr><w:ind w:firstLineChars="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${Computer}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="006A378C" w:rsidRDefault="006A378C" w:rsidP="006A378C"/><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>note</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="006166EE" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="006166EE"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${WORKEXP}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:tab/><w:t>${WE_StartDate}-${WE_EndDate}</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:tab/></w:r><w:r><w:tab/><w:t>${WE_Company}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="006166EE" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="006166EE"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/WORKEXP}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="006A378C" w:rsidRDefault="006A378C" w:rsidP="0002737E"/><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>工</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>作</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>经</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>历</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="006166EE" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="006166EE"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${WORKEXP2}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:tab/><w:t>${WE_StartDate}-${WE_EndDate}</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:tab/></w:r><w:r><w:tab/><w:t>${WE_Company}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="00B84EBB"><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="420" w:firstLine="420"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>【</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> ${WE_CompanyDetail} </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>】</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="00B84EBB"><w:pPr><w:ind w:leftChars="400" w:left="840"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${WE_Title} - ${WE_Department}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="00B84EBB"><w:pPr><w:ind w:leftChars="400" w:left="840"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>obj：</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>${WE_Leader}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="00B84EBB"><w:pPr><w:ind w:leftChars="400" w:left="840"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>obj：</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>${WE_UnderlingNumber}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="00B84EBB"><w:pPr><w:ind w:leftChars="400" w:left="840"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>obj：</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="00955A8D" w:rsidRDefault="00955A8D" w:rsidP="00955A8D"><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="420" w:firstLine="420"/><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${SUMMARY}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="00B84EBB"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="a5"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr><w:ind w:leftChars="603" w:left="1686" w:firstLineChars="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${WE_Summary}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="006166EE" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="00B84EBB"><w:pPr><w:ind w:leftChars="400" w:left="840"/><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="006166EE"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/SUMMARY}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="00B84EBB"><w:pPr><w:ind w:leftChars="400" w:left="840"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:lastRenderedPageBreak/><w:t>obj：</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="00CA06C6" w:rsidRDefault="00955A8D" w:rsidP="00CA06C6"><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="420" w:firstLine="420"/><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${ACHIVMENT}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="00B84EBB"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="a5"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr><w:ind w:leftChars="603" w:left="1686" w:firstLineChars="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${WE_Achivment}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="006166EE" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="00B84EBB"><w:pPr><w:ind w:leftChars="400" w:left="840"/><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="006166EE"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/ACHIVMENT}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"/><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="006166EE" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="006166EE"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/WORKEXP2}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="006A378C" w:rsidRDefault="006A378C" w:rsidP="0002737E"/><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>项</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>目</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>经</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>历</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"/><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>顾</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>问</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>简</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>评</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>技</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">    </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>能：</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="009A07F0"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${EXPERIENCE}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="006A378C"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="a5"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr><w:ind w:firstLineChars="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${Experience}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="009A07F0"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/EXPERIENCE}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>obj：</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="009A07F0"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${PERSONALITY}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="006A378C"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="a5"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr><w:ind w:firstLineChars="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${Personality}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="009A07F0"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/PERSONALITY}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>obj：</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="006A378C"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="a5"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr><w:ind w:firstLineChars="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${Salary}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>obj：</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="009A07F0"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${MOTIVATION}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="006A378C"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="a5"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr><w:ind w:firstLineChars="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${Motivation}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="009A07F0"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/MOTIVATION}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/></w:rPr><w:t>obj：</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="009A07F0"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${HIGHLIGHT}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="006A378C"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="a5"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr><w:ind w:firstLineChars="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${Highlight}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="0002737E" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="0002737E" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="009A07F0"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/HIGHLIGHT}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00F72498" w:rsidRDefault="00F72498" w:rsidP="0002737E"/><w:p w:rsidR="00454E5D" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="00454E5D" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="009A07F0"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${USERDEFINE}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00454E5D" w:rsidRDefault="00454E5D" w:rsidP="0002737E"><w:r><w:t>${UserDefineKey}:</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00454E5D" w:rsidRPr="006166EE" w:rsidRDefault="00454E5D" w:rsidP="00BC134E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="006166EE"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${USERDEFINELIST}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00454E5D" w:rsidRDefault="00454E5D" w:rsidP="00454E5D"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="a5"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr><w:ind w:firstLineChars="0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>${UserDefineValue}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00454E5D" w:rsidRPr="006166EE" w:rsidRDefault="00454E5D" w:rsidP="00BC134E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="006166EE"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/USERDEFINELIST}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00454E5D" w:rsidRPr="009A07F0" w:rsidRDefault="00454E5D" w:rsidP="00BC134E"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="009A07F0"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="a6"/></w:rPr><w:t>${/USERDEFINE}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00454E5D" w:rsidRDefault="00454E5D" w:rsidP="0002737E"/><w:sectPr w:rsidR="00454E5D"><w:headerReference w:type="even" r:id="rId7"/><w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId8"/><w:footerReference w:type="even" r:id="rId9"/><w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId10"/><w:headerReference w:type="first" r:id="rId11"/><w:footerReference w:type="first" r:id="rId12"/><w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/><w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1800" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1800" w:header="851" w:footer="992" w:gutter="0"/><w:cols w:space="720"/><w:docGrid w:type="lines" w:linePitch="312"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>';


echo '<pre>';

$blockname='EDUCATION';

preg_match(
    '/(<w:p\s.*>\${' . $blockname . '}<\/w:.*?p>)(.*)(<w:p\s.*>\${\/' . $blockname . '}<\/w:.*?p>)/s',
    $string,
    $matches
);

print_r($matches);

preg_match(
    '/(.*)(<w:p\s.*>\${' . $blockname . '}<\/w:.*?p>)(.*)(<w:p\s.*>\${\/' . $blockname . '}<\/w:.*?p>)/s',
    $string,
    $matches
);

print_r($matches);


?>
```

Comment: try `.*?`...........

Comment: Please include the testing file in the question. Don't link elsewhere on the internet

Comment: Because the test string too long, so I put it in a test file.

Comment: It isn't a preg_match bug, your pattern causes too much backtracking. use DOMDocument.

Comment: Much backtracking? If I cut the string short, it worked. And if I change the $blockname, ie. use 'USER' or other word, it will be work.

Comment: As @CasimiretHippolyte mentioned, it's due to too much backtracking, which exceeds the number allowed in the default configuration. If you catch the return value of `preg_match`, it gives `false`, instead of `0`, [which means an error has occurred](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27868983/3764814) on how to change that limit, but you should use XML APIs instead of regex for such tasks anyway.