# regex for matching lines with exatcly n times a pipe

Tags: regex, grep

I am using grep to match lines which have exactly 52 pipelines (|). The grep command I am using is:

```
grep -nP "^(.*?\|){52}"
```

`-P` because the lazy modifier `?` does not work otherwise. When I run this, the following message is displayed: `PCRE's backtracking limit is exceeded`. I guess there is something wrong with perl-like regex here.

- Am I running out of memory?
- Is the problem in the regex I am using?
- Is there any better regex I can use?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not use `grep -En "^([^|]*\|){52}"`? BTW, I cannot repro in grep (GNU grep) 2.25.

Comment: cleaner approch would be `awk -F'|' 'NF==53' yourfile`

Comment: If you want to only match a string with 52 `|` chars, a `grep` regex approach would be [`grep -En "^([^|]*\|){52}[^|]*$"`](http://rextester.com/FPODH67998)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PCRE pattern (that only matches 52 occurrences of any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to and including `|` char, and does not check any text beyond that) contains a repeated capturing group, when the engine matches, it also places each 0+ chars before each `|` and the `|` char into a group, and then re-writes the value upon each iteration. In some implementations, it causes the error you provided.

Note you do not need a PCRE regex for the task since to match any char but `|` you may use `[^|]` and then use a mere POSIX ERE pattern (enabled with `-E` option) with `grep`:

```
grep -En "^([^|]*\|){52}[^|]*$"
```

Note the `[^|]*$` added at the end. It matches any 0+ chars other than `|` and then assert the end of line position. So, only lines containing 53 `|`-separated fields are matched.

Else, you might consider an awk solution (as PS suggests):

```
awk -F'|' '{if (NF==53) {print NR ":" $0;}}'
```

where we check for 53 `|`-separated fields and print the line number, `:` and the line itself.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor The grep -En "^([^|]*\|){52}[^|]*$" solution worked fine ;)

Comment: Re: "In some implementations, it causes the error you provided.": where is to read the details? Why the limit is hard-coded (is it?) instead of "limited only by available memory"?

Comment: @pmor [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27868983/3832970) you can get more relevant details (PHP also uses the PCRE regex engine, now, PCRE2).